# AtomicInteger's get() vs intValue()

Tags: java, atomic

Why does AtomicInteger have both a int get() and an int intValue()?  I see it also has float floatValue() among others, from Number.  Does one have implications related to maintaining atomicity of the AtomicInteger param, or are both interchangeable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They should be interchangeable.  Here is the relevant part of the source code for `AtomicInteger`:

```
public int intValue() {
    return get();
}
```

Comment: This is not true.
get is final.
intValue is not final.

Answer (score 7):

`intValue` definition:

```
/**
 * Returns the value of this {@code AtomicInteger} as an {@code int}.
 */
public int intValue() {
    return get();
}
```

`get` definition:

```
/**
 * Gets the current value.
 *
 * @return the current value
 */
public final int get() {
    return value;
}
```

You can clearly see that `get` method is `final`. `final` methods cannot be overridden.

If we extend the AtomicInteger class, we cannot override the `get` method, but we can override the `intValue` method.

Comment: This answer explained the difference between these two methods. But, Why we need them for `AtomicInteger` is still un-explained.

Answer (score 2):

From [`Number` class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html):

*The abstract class Number is the superclass of classes BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, and Short.*

From [AtomicInteger documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#intValue%28%29)

*Description copied from class:

Number Returns the value of the specified number as an int. This may involve rounding or truncation.*

As `AtomicInteger` extends abstract class `Number`, abstract method `intValue()` has to be implemented. They are equal in this case. For other types (e.g. `BigDecimal`, `Double` or `Float`) it makes much more sense.